# What can the implementation do with semantic requirements for concepts?

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer, c++-concepts

I'm confused about what the purpose and meaning of semantic requirements for concepts is. For example, [[iterator.concept.contiguous] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.contiguous#2) lists a number of semantic requirements for the `std::contiguous_iterator` concept.
Among other requirements, `to_address(a) == addressof(*a)` has to be true for an iterator `a`.

These are not part of the definition in the first paragraph:

> ```cpp
> template<class I>
>   concept contiguous_iterator =
>     random_access_iterator<I> &&
>     derived_from<ITER_CONCEPT(I), contiguous_iterator_tag> &&
>     is_lvalue_reference_v<iter_reference_t<I>> &&
>     same_as<iter_value_t<I>, remove_cvref_t<iter_reference_t<I>>> &&
>     requires(const I& i) {
>       { to_address(i) } -> same_as<add_pointer_t<iter_reference_t<I>>>;
>     };
> ```

What exactly can an implementation do with these extra semantic constraints? What if a concept falsely appears satisfied, even though the semantic requirements are not met?

For example, say I have an iterator `T` which meets all the requirements of the `std::contiguous_iterator` concept in the first paragraph, but not the semantic constraints. Is `std::contiguos_iterator<T>` still guaranteed to be `true`? Is the implementation allowed to diagnose these extra requirements and make `std::contiguous_iterator<T>` `false`? Is it undefined or unspecified behavior to rely on `std::contiguous_iterator<T>` being `true`?

---

*Note: there are numerous other such requirements. For example, `std::strict_weak_order` adds purely semantic requirements on top of `std::relation`, and `std::regular_invocable` adds purely semantic requirements on top of `std::invocable`.*

Comment: Similar to prerequires of functions/type elsewhere (`operator<` should already be a strict weak order to work in `std::sort`).

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.requirements?

Comment: "*What exactly can an implementation do with these extra semantic constraints?*" Basically nothing. For some `int f(int) { ... }`, it meets the syntactic requirements of both `invocable<int>` and `regular_invocable<int>`. The compiler has no way of knowing whether it is equality preserved except by looking at the full definition, which may not be visible.

Answer (score 2):

Semantic requirements are... semantic. They regard the *meaning* of code, not the structure of it. They are things which cannot reasonably be detected by a compiler.

The standard represents this distinction as the difference between a [concept being "satisfied" and "modeled":](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/res.on.requirements):

> [res.on.requirements]
>
> A sequence Args of template arguments is said to model a concept C if Args satisfies C (13.5.2) and meets all semantic requirements (if any) given in the specification of C.
>
> If the validity or meaning of a program depends on whether a sequence of template arguments models a concept, and the concept is satisfied but not modeled, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Since most functions constrained on templates talk about what is "modeled" rather than "satisfied", violating semantic requirements is ill-formed, NDR.